# I migrated existing android project to Android X using Android Studio, but I am unable to import/resolve any androidx library - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I recently migrated an old android project to Android X using the automated Android Studio route. My gradle dependencies are all there, but I am unable to use any androidx library. Can you please advise on what I am doing wrong? Every time I try to import an Android X library (i.e. import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) I get the cannot resolve error

compileSDKVersion and targetSdkVersion =32 and minSdkVersion =26

I also have gradle properties include the following

android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

[image]

Project Level Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0'
```

and any other necessary dependencies in your build.gradle file. Sync project with gradle and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried that but again I can't import anything androidX related. It seems as like the library is not downloading or something at all. (See screenshot above). Is it something to do with my AndroidStudio not connecting to the library?

Comment: Did your project successfully sync with gradle?  Also can you show your project level build.gradle file?

Comment: It did sync successfully with the gradle. I've added the project level gradle file above. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Oh. Your gradle file is okay. Can you try invalidating cache and restarting your Android studio?

Comment: Just tried that as well, still no luck importing androidx library. Any other idea or recommendation I can try?

Comment: Okay. Can you put the imports but ignore the error. Just click run and see if the project builds successfully? Sometimes Android Studio could be weird, and it has worked for some persons that way.

Comment: Still no luck :( . Is it a setting in android studio that is unable to pull new online libraries?

Comment: So sorry you've been through these without luck still. Try changing your gradle version , maybe it could help. Preferably to version 7.0.2 ( no special reason for this; that's what I'm currently using ).  Also, are you applying the appropriate plugins in your app level build gradle file?